# How to get one entry in a Jlist to work with entries in another JList?

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, jlist

Bear with me. I have a denist program with 3 JList's. A patient JList that adds patients, a history jlist that adds the patients history and an invoice history that should link with the history jlist and the patient jlist. I have them all writing to each Jlist respectably but my aim is: when i click on a patient , their history will pop up in the history JList and the invoice will appear in the Invoice Jlist.

How would i go about this? I have id's in each jlist. I think this would be the right way to go about it.

More than happy to send the program via email if needed.

Need help!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just add ListSelectionListener(s) to your JLists and when the selection changes find the appropriate object for your other JLists to display.
You can call `list.getModel().getElementAt(i)` to get the elements contained in the list. Find the appropriate one by whatever mechanism you have to identify linked items. Once you have the item just call `list.setSelectedValue(yourObject, shouldScroll)` and that's it.

Comment: Keep getting errors whenever I try to add a ListSelectionListener to the JList. Could you give me an example of how to implement what your trying to say.

Comment: What kind of errors? `list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() { public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) { /* TODO Auto-generated method stub */ }});` works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks that gives no errors. I'm still rather unsure on how to link them. How will i link one patient with one history and one invoice. :/

Comment: a working example like how to link the patient to the history jlist would help me greatly!!

Comment: Well either your Patient object has a history object member variable in which case it's trivial, or they share some sort of ID in which case you would have to iterate over them and find the matching ID. In any case you will most certainly need to connect things like the history to your Patient objects for other parts of your program anyway.

Comment: Ah forget it. Not very helpful to be honest but thanks anyway

Comment: Well what do you want to read? A complete program ready for you to copy&paste? If you are asking these questions you obviously have a) no knowledge of Software Engineering at all and b) your code must be a huge mess.

Comment: Code's working fine buddy thanks very much :) I ask questions for people to answer. Not some smart arse like you giving me stupid answers so please get off my post, maybe somebody else could answer me properly .. thanks very much 8-)